# Fazer PHP imprimir nomes em determinadas classes

Tags: php

O seguinte código em Javascript tem a função de **imprimir um texto** nos elementos com a classe `exibir`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".exibir").text("Olá Mundo!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="exibir">Isso é um parágrafo.</p>
<p class="exibir">Isso é um parágrafo.</p>
```

O código que citei tipo "maqueia" os textos contidos, queria fazer o mesmo, só que em PHP, pois estou criando uma página que precisa já vir imprimida do servidor (`PHP`), ao invés de ser alterada depois de carregada a página (`Javascript`).

> Como fazer esta mesma função em **PHP** ?

Estou criando uma página que contém 4 textos iguais no corpo da página.

Preciso de certa forma setar o que será exibido nesses 4 textos no cabeçalho da página, ou seja, lá no cabeçalho "`<head>`" eu possa definir via `PHP`, o que será exibido nesses 4 textos idênticos que se encontram no corpo da página "`<body>`".

Comment: Utilizar um [interpretador de DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) é uma opção?

Comment: Qualquer resposta que possa vir a solucionar o problema é sempre bem vinda :)

Comment: Não posso responder sua pergunta, pois a mesma está como pendente. Seu exemplo de Javascript nos dá uma ideia do que pretende fazer, mas ajudaria a esclarecer exatamente o que quer fazer se colocasse algum exemplo do que tentou fazer em PHP.

Comment: @PanterA Dá um voto lá pra reabrir :P, pior que não tentei fazer em `PHP`, pois sou novo com PHP.

Answer (score 2):

OJavaScript executa pelo browser do usuário.

O PHP executa no chamado "backend", ou seja, necessita de uma requisição ao servidor onde o PHP se encontra.

Não existe função como no JavaScript, capaz de interagir diretamente com o 
DOM da página HTML exibida no browser.

O que poderia fazer é, algo desse tipo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".exibir").text("<?php echo $_GET['nome'];?>");
});
```

Mas não está muito claro o que realmente pretende pois há meios diferentes de resolver. O modo mais adequado depende do objetivo final, além das circunstâncias envolvidas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Dani! :) Vou tentar te explicar melhor, o código que citei tipo "maqueia" os textos contidos, queria fazer o mesmo, só que em PHP. Exemplo, eu coloco "Bom dia!" em um lugar no PHP, e então as classes que tiverem a classe `exibir`, terão seus textos alterados para "Bom dia!". É porque estou fazendo uma página, e esse texto deve já vir imprimido na página, ao invés de imprimir após a página ser carregada. Ah, Daniel, me perdoe qualquer coisa, sei que as vezes você fica meio irritado com minhas perguntas e tals... é que eu sou novo com PHP, e preciso de ajuda. :'(